# adding extra fields to todo.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

How do you add extra fields into todo.js?

```
  initialize: function() {
  this.input    = this.$("#new-todo");
  Todos.bind('add',   this.addOne, this);
  Todos.bind('reset', this.addAll, this);
  Todos.bind('all',   this.render, this);

  Todos.fetch();
},
```

i think its the above code thats troubling, #new-todo is the div id where the text field is.

i add another 'this.input' with the id of the new field but it doesn't pick it up.
how do i add additional elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `this.$` only search beneath the element connected to the view. If you have your input element outside of the element the view is connected to, you can try to use just `$("#another-todo")` or similar.

Comment: like this? this.input = this.$("another-todo")

Comment: No, like this: `this.anothertodo = $("#another-todo")` if I understand you correctly.

Comment: this is not working, is there somehow i can send you the whole code